# Issue setting Low Variables file path with Focus Lab EE Master Config

Tags: low-variables, focus-lab-master-config

I'm saving my Low Variables as files above web root in a directory named *_vars* and setting the file path in my [Focus Lab EE Master Config](https://github.com/focuslabllc/ee-master-config) file like this:

```
$env_config['low_variables_save_as_files'] = 'y';
$env_config['low_variables_one_way_sync'] = 'y';
$env_config['low_variables_file_path'] = $base_path . '/../_vars/';
```

The variables work fine on my local environment and I can see them in the CP. After pushing up to my dev environment I don't see the variables in the dev CP even though I see them on the dev server in the *_vars* directory. Because of this the variables aren't rendering. I even tried creating a variable directly in the CP and there's no file generated in the designated folder. Thoughts on what could be happening here?

Comment: Can you verify if the path is writable?

Comment: Directory is set to 775.

Comment: Are you sure the `$base_path` is correct? Does it point to the correct folder?

Comment: Yes, because when I created a variable within the CP it generated a file in the correct directory. I think I'm just going to generate them all in the CP on dev so that when I push the files up they have a coordinating file in place.

Comment: The One Way Sync feature doesn't create vars/files on the server automatically when syncing. Is that what you were expecting?

Comment: That is what I was expecting. Either way, I still need to create the variable in the CP to create the file first?